# Title: ImportError with ptitprince and seaborn - '_CategoricalScatterPlotter' not found

Tags: seaborn

I'm experiencing an import issue when trying to use the ptitprince library alongside seaborn. After installing seaborn version 0.11.0 as required by ptitprince 0.2.7, I encountered a dependency conflict indicating that seaborn 0.13.0 is incompatible. Upon adjusting the seaborn version, I tried to import ptitprince, but I received the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_CategoricalScatterPlotter' from 'seaborn.categorical'
```

It seems that _CategoricalScatterPlotter is not available in the seaborn.categorical module. I have checked my seaborn version to confirm I'm running the version I just installed is 0.13.0

I'm not sure if this issue is due to a version mismatch or if the class/function has been removed or renamed in a recent seaborn update. I'm looking for any guidance on how to resolve this issue so I can use ptitprince for my data visualization needs.

Has anyone else faced this issue, or does anyone know how to solve this or work around it?

I'm encountering a compatibility issue between ptitprince version 0.2.7 and seaborn. When I install ptitprince, it requires seaborn version 0.11.0. However, after installation, my terminal reports a conflict with seaborn 0.13.0 being installed, which is incompatible with ptitprince 0.2.7.

Here's the error message from my terminal:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
ptitprince 0.2.7 requires seaborn==0.11, but you have seaborn 0.13.0 which is incompatible.
```

After downgrading seaborn to 0.11.0 to match the ptitprince requirements, I attempted to import ptitprince and was met with the following ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_CategoricalScatterPlotter' from 'seaborn.categorical'
```